# Registry pattern - the difference with reference and without

Tags: php, design-patterns, registry-pattern

Following this [guide](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part/), but it is always difficult for me to understand references in PHP. What is the purpose of using reference in the params below?

```
public function register($name, &$object)
{
    $this->registries[$name] =& $object;
}
public function &getRegistry($name)
{
    return $this->registries[$name];
}
```

Without the references:

```
public function register($name, $object)
{
    $this->registries[$name] = $object;
}

public function getRegistry($name)
{
    return $this->registries[$name];
}
```

It works fine too without the the references, so what is the advantages having them?

Comment: If `$object` is actually and object, then I'm not sure there is any advantage in these examples.

Comment: Passing by reference passes a reference to the object, not a copy of the object. If you pass by reference you can modify the object within the method and the modifications will be applied to the object passed as an argument.

Comment: @Rasmus If the `$object` is *an object*, modifications will affect it either way, with or without explicit reference. Objects aren't copied on assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Objects needed to be explicitly passed by reference back in the PHP 4 dark ages. Since PHP 5.0 objects essentially *are* a reference and it doesn't make any difference whether you pass the object reference by reference or not. Every guide on the matter will tell you to omit passing objects by reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It does make a difference. If you pass and store the object as a reference then changing the value of the originally passed variable (e.g. setting it to a different object or even other type) will affect the value in `$this->registries` as well.

Comment: Yes, fair enough, if you use references then your code will behave according to the rules of references, which is often something you'll flat out want to avoid, except for very specific occasions. This isn't one of those occasions.